# Is it possible to a drill hole in the bottom of a terracotta gardening pot?

Tags: drill, gardening

I would like to make some drainage holes in the bottom of some terracotta pots I have. I am tempted to use a drill but am not sure whether this will work and how  should go about it. Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: I've never tried this, but I'd try drilling some test holes first in a broken pot. I'd guess you'd need to get the speed and pressure just right to avoid breakage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place your pots on a piece of large enough wood that you wont mind having a few holes in a flat and stable surface.

If you use an electric drill mostly you can set the speed.Or a battery operated one is good. Put it on 25-40% roughly. MAKE SURE THE HAMMER EFFECT IS OFF. Use a new sharp mortar drill ( cheaper than tile drill) and put water in the base- Not flooded just enough to keep the drill cool because you going to need to drill for a constant time (2-6 minutes depeing on thickness) applying slight pressure and slight tilting the drill form side to side every few moments.

If these are thick pots you will be OK. But if they are the small windows pots you have to be more gentle.. even using tile drills i have broken tiles in half.. And i have had good success using mortar drills on tiles... Just be gentle and make sure to keep the drill bit cool other wise it will go blunt and you will be drilling your whole life.

:)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to using a tile bit, I would recommend using a hand drill instead of a power one. I use mine for drilling thin panels or other delicate material.

Comment: This *is* an answer - you are adding new information.

Answer (score 3):

[Tile hole saw](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-202205611/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053)

As this works for tile, it should work for terracotta too.

Comment: The link here is now broken

Answer (score 2):

I do it with a simple electric drill machine using 2mm bit. I make multiple holes in a circular form and then cut through these holes to make one hold of desired size.

Comment: I wonder if this dulls the 2mm bit so that in later use for metal or hard wood the bit does not work well. Perhaps label the bit so that if later used for hard material you can watch for evidence that the bit has been dulled.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, test it. If the test fails with a regular pointed drill bit, try a diamond core drill bit. That should do the trick.

Anyway, submerge in water or at least spray, don't press too much, don't go too fast. Take the bit out every now and then and clean it.